# Create StrawPoll.me poll with Node

Tags: javascript, node.js, api, post, request

I was trying to create a new poll with Strawpoll.me API.

```
var poll = { title: 'test', options: [ '1', '2' ] };

var request = require('request');

request.post(
    'https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls',
    {
        body: poll,
        json: true
    },
    function (error, response, body) {
        console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

But I cannot create new poll. I'm receiving "statusCode": 307 and empty body.

StrawPoll doc's: https://github.com/strawpoll/strawpoll/wiki/API

What can I do with that? Thx!

Comment: please include all relevant code in the question and not just link to it as links can rot..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add this option `followAllRedirects: true,`

```
var poll = { title: 'test', options: [ '1', '2' ] };

var request = require('request');

request.post({
  url: 'https://strawpoll.me/api/v2/polls',
  followAllRedirects: true, // <----
  body: poll,
  json: true
},
    function (error, response, body) {
        if (!error && response.statusCode == 200) {
            console.log(body)
        }
    }
);
```

Response:

```
{ id: 10585477,
  title: 'test',
  options: [ '1', '2' ],
  votes: [ 0, 0 ],
  multi: false,
  dupcheck: 'normal',
  captcha: false }
```